# How To Read a Song in python letter by letter while playing the sound file of that song

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to make python read a song from a text file while playing a song at the same time.
The way it reads the song is sort of like how the song from [portal(Still Alive)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36reZ9-3VK0) is being played.

its kinda of tricky i think, but i need python to print out the song each letter at a time while keeping the pace with the actual song.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards!

### EDIT

```
import urllib.request # Example URL 

url = "http://ntl.matrix.com.br/pfilho/oldies_list/top/lyrics/black_or_white.txt" # Open URL: returns file-like object 
lyrics = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # Read raw data, this will return a "bytes object" 
text = lyrics.read() # Print raw data 
print(text) # Print decoded data: 
print(text.decode('utf-8'))
```

EDIT:

ok , so i think this may be very broad to answer, so here's what i want to do: Just be able to print each character by reading it from a textfile and be able to set the speed of reading/printing it.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: 1) build exhaustive list of time points in the song where you want your text displayed. 2) play song 3) monitor playtime and output text as needed based on list generated in #1

Comment: @wnnmaw Well.. so far , i've looked at the internet and searched some documentation, and found some code. this code reads a text file and prints out its contents.

`code`
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request

# Example URL
url="http://ntl.matrix.com.br/pfilho/oldies_list/top/lyrics/black_or_white.txt"

# Open URL: returns file-like object
lyrics=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# Read raw data, this will return a "bytes object"
text=lyrics.read()

# Print raw data
print(text)

# Print decoded data:
print(text.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: @MarcB I am new to python and i have just recently started learning how to read files. any code to help me with you solution so i can have a look at?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not difficult to code (for a novice), but it requires the exhaustive list that @MarcB is talking about. You need to know how long to wait between printing each character which is...exhaustive.

Comment: As an alternative to exhaustively specifying the time points for every word, you could perform voice recognition on the song to identify when each lyric is sung. However, voice recognition barely works on people speaking slowly and clearly with no accent and no background noise. If you can get it working for mumbling rock stars, you'd probably be eligible for some kind of prestigious computing award. Not very suitable for one's first programming project.

Comment: @DharmilAsawla found the source of your code for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15773116/541208 Have you tried writing anything yourself? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some basic code that assumes you have a lot of information before hand.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
# For python 2 import this
#from itertools import izip as zip
# Delay in seconds to wait before printing each *character* of the song lyrics
time_delays = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]
song_lyrics = "thesong"

print "Let's sing a song..."
for song_char, char_delay in zip(song_lyrics, time_delays):
    sleep(char_delay)
    sys.stdout.write(song_char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Hope that helps. The reason I use `sys.stdout` instead of `print` is because it is easier to control and you need to flush the buffer otherwise the screen will only update when the buffer is full.

Comment: The code gives me this error :
`code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/songtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name izip`

Comment: Ah you must be using python 3? I fixed the code above. `zip` in python 3 is equivalent to `itertools.izip` in python 2.